# How to get all values associated with the same key in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Class that looks like this

```
public class VegetablesPriceNode
{
 public string Country{get;set;}
 public Dictionary<string,string> VegetableDictionary{get;set;}
}
```

Then I get each Individual VegetablesPriceNode in the form of a List

```
List<VegetablesPriceNode> = //I get this object after parsing.
```

There are same keys in all the VegetableDictionary but for different countries, which I need to show it horizontally.

```
Veggies   Afghanistan.   Bahrain
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Onions  | $2.00       |  $1.00  ....
Potatoes| $3.00       |  $1.50  ....
.......

public static void Main()
{
   // I get a List<VegetablesPriceNode> from some place
   // Need to extract all values for the same key from all dictionaries 
   
   // I tried to extract all keys first using 
   var  = vegetablesPriceNodeList.SelectMany(x => x.VegetableDictionary.Select(x => x.Key)).ToHashSet();

   // I chose HashSet because all keys were getting appended and there is no unique.

}
```

How can I get extract the same key information iterating over all dictionaries for all countries?
e.g I want all Onions prices from all countries. so loop through all dictionaries for Onions as the key and get their values?

Is the above way of extracting keys first and then fetching all values for this key is ideal? or is there a better solution?

Since I am using DataTable to store this information
the DataTable uses object[]
the object I am getting is List

Expected:
List of string values which look like

```
"Onions","$2.00","$3.00"
```

Sample data:

```
[{"Country":"Afghanistan","VegetableDictionary":{"Onions":"$1.00","Potatoes":"$1.40"}},{"Country":"Bahrain","VegetableDictionary":{"Onions":"$3.00","Potatoes":"$3.40"}}]
```

Comment: "How can I get extract the same key information iterating over all dictionaries for all countries?" In what format? Just a list of values, or a dictionary from country to price? Note that if you could provide a [mcve] with sample data and expected result, that would make it easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet Edited the question, let me know if its still unclear. Thanks :)

Comment: It's still not really clear, no - and it's *far* from a complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is your desired output.

I believe something similar:

```
[["Onions","$1.00","$3.00"],["Potatoes","$1.40","$3.40"]]
```

I made an example, I hope it could be useful in your use case:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RPFZen

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class VegetablesPriceNode
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> VegetableDictionary { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "[{\"Country\":\"Afghanistan\",\"VegetableDictionary\":{\"Onions\":\"$1.00\",\"Potatoes\":\"$1.40\"}},{\"Country\":\"Bahrain\",\"VegetableDictionary\":{\"Onions\":\"$3.00\",\"Potatoes\":\"$3.40\"}}]";

        var vegetablesPriceNodeList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VegetablesPriceNode>>(json);

        var obj = vegetablesPriceNodeList
            .SelectMany(x =>
                x.VegetableDictionary
                    .Select(x => x.Key)
            )
            .Distinct()
            .Select((k) =>
                vegetablesPriceNodeList
                    .Select(v => v.VegetableDictionary[k])
                    .Prepend(k)
                    .ToArray()
            ).ToArray();

        var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but it crashes for dictionary if there are keys present in some and not in other dictionaries. do you know how to handle that?

Comment: You could use a default value, for example, .Select(v => v.VegetableDictionary.ContainsKey(k) ? v.VegetableDictionary[k] : "$0.00")